# Cannot drop a schema in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to drop the schema `masterdata` from a `postgres` database, but it does not work. I am using `PostgreSQL 9.5.` I have 2 databses, one of them has the `masterdata` schema, which I want to drop. Here is the structure (in `DBeaver`):

[image]

My first attempt was just to execute the `SQL` statement `DROP SCHEMA masterdata` in `DBeaver`, but it tells me, that such a schema does not exist (but it does show it, as we can see in the picture!). Maybe, it does not know, in which of the 2 databses to look for this schema? If so, then how to specify it? I was looking for a way to specify the database, but did not find anything.

However, my second attempt was to use `psql` and to type the command

```
psql -U postgres -d bobd -h localhost
```

So here I concretely specify, which databse to use! `psql` does not answer anything, it just asks for the next command. And when I type `\dn` to view the current schemas, then the schema `masterdata` is still there! Also, the data in the tables is still there. I tried the same with other users instead of the user `postgres` (also with the owner of the schema to remove), but the result is the same.

Any ideas, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your DBeaver session was probably connected to the wrong database (`postgres`?).

Do it from the `psql` session, that is easiest.

Right after `\dn` showed you that there is indeed such a schema, enter

```
DROP SCHEMA masterdata;
```

It may complain that there are objects in that schema. Then you can use

```
DROP SCHEMA masterdata CASCADE;
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add in the question, that of course i did run DROP SCHEMA masterdata and it had no effect. My mistake :(  But now I tried it again and ... it worked! :) Maybe it was because I added "CASCADE" ... though, as far I remember, I was trying this too. So in the end, I have no idea what exactly did the trick. I also did as Bo said in his answer to look at the namespaces. Indeed, there was no namespace "masterdata". But tehere was some strange namespace like "pg_toast" so I removed that. Maybe that had some effect too - i don't know. I any case thanks a lot!

Comment: If you actually removed `pg_toast` (which I doubt you can), your database would be - well - toast. This is where overlength data are stored, so without it some of your data would be missing.

Comment: Yeah YOU NEED TO TYPE IT TWICE IN ORDER TO TAKE EFFECT WHICH IT IS WEIRD.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer No, you need not.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your schema name contains characters that do not display or display differently (maybe capital letters) in DBeaver. I suggest you check names by running following query:

```
SELECT '~~' || nspname || '~~' FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace;
```

Try adding quotes around schema name if you have added capital letters when creating schema.